# Methodical way of converting regular expressions to nfa's?

Tags: regex, compiler-construction

I am in compilers class and the professor just threw at us how to convert regex to nfa's without any method or rules. Is there a methodical way to approach the problem? I find it hard to deal with why all the epsilons exist and how do i construct an nfa given regex. Thank you for any help.

Comment: [This presentation](http://www.slideshare.net/mukeshnt/convert-regular-expression-to-nfa-presentation) may be of some help.

Comment: @BradChristie That presentation is so short and opaque that I almost laughed out loud.

Comment: Short presentation but it tells more than my professor did in two hours. Thanks BradChristie. It seems the logic is to construct separate nfa's and then glue them with epsilons.

Comment: @Jeff: I was going for a visual (shows how to explode the possibilities, then compile them). user: Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a Thompson NFA. See the [article by Russ Cox](http://swtch.com/~rsc/regexp/regexp1.html). It is made in the C language.